# Hide specific div depending on the page you're seing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 divs in the bottom of the homepage (kinda like a carousel) and when clicked, opens a page with more details about what's in each div.
I have the homepage + homepage/div1-details + homepage/div2-details + homepage/div3-details + homepage/div4-details.

The problem is: when i'm in, for example, homepage/div1-details, that carousel of divs is present in the bottom as well, but I don't want to show the div1 when I'm in homepage/div1-details because doesn't make seance to have a link for the page you're already in.

The goal is to make a js code that hides the div correspondent to the page you are seeing. In other words, hide div1 for homepage/div1-details, hide div2 for homepage/div2-details and so long.

Html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="success-cases">
  <div class="row"> <!-- populated by javascript -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have an array with info to populate the div, and inside there's a field called 'slug' that completes the url for the details page of each div. Each div , depending if the detail page is created, can have 1 of 2 possible links, that it's done like this (I don't know if it's relevant for what I want, but it might help I think):

```
  $( ".success" ).each( function () {
    $( this ).bind (
      "click",
      function(){
        item = getObjectInArrayByField (successCasesList, 'company_slug', $(this).attr('data-caso'));
        if (item.has_dedicated_page == true) {
          window.location.href = '/!/success-cases-' + $(this).attr('data-caso');
        } else {
          window.open(item.company_website,
            '_blank'
          )
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

I know it's not super specific because I'm not showing all the code, but I'd like to have a generic idea of how I could do this, keeping in mind that I'm fairly newbie to js in general.
thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with how carousel's manipulate the page, but I might mention jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()`? you could start page up with them all hidden and just show them on a click event? If you have any animations then they would no longer work, but it would be the functionality you're looking for

Comment: @Turk sadly, they need to be showed right away, the only click event has to be to make the divs "linkable"

Comment: So are the page URLs div1-details or div2-details? From the description, it sounds like homepage is a directory and the various detail pages are within that. Am I right? If so, simply split the filename (var myDiv = location.href.split("-") ) on the hyphen, then use myDiv[0] in a hide()

Comment: @Snowmonkey yes, you are correct. I'm slightly confused by your split explanation tho

Comment: I asked so that I can work on a full answer. Thanks for the clarification. Let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's as simple as just hiding the #div1 for div1-details.html, the #div2 for div2-details.html etc., then this should be all you need (it would be in a common js file, used by all the div*-details.html pages):

```
// the url of the page starts with the id of the div we want to hide
var myDivToHide = window.location.href.split("-")[0];
// then we simply hide that one div
if(myDivToHide) { $("#"+myDivToHide).hide(); }
```

This requires, though, that each div has a UNIQUE id.

Comment: Okay, this didn't do the trick, I'm guessing because all the div*s have the same class `.sucess-case`, but each one has a `data-caso` property that is populated by the slug name inside of the array, that gives them the url for the `/div*-details`

Comment: Do the divs have unique ids? for example, is it div1 / div2? I handled the selector wrong, as this was a thought experiment... Hang on. Where is the data-caso attribute set, and is THAT unique?

Comment: They do not have id's. when the div is being populated, it gets this `data-caso="' + item.company_slug`  (right next to the class) that is in the array var SucessCasesList = [ company_slug: ' ']

Comment: But the item.company_slug has no relation to the div1/div2/div3 thing? Then you might want to use a reference array.